# Error missing ‘)’ symbol grub

Tags: grub2, 16.10

Trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop (I have 16.10 and it won’t upgrade for some bizarre reason), in the past I’ve been able to follow these instructions to install the OS

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1599293

However when I’m executing the command to create the loop back I get:

error: missing ‘)’ symbol

And nothing else works, I’ve searched up and down and have not been able to find what that error means.

Any help will be greatly appreciated 
[image]

Comment: Double check your grub boot stanza for a missing ). I used loopback but found my older stanza needed .efi removed which they added several versions ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `(hd0,1)` **without the space** after the comma:

Use...

`loopbak loop (hd0,1)/home/pepe/Downloads/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso`

Instead of...

`loopbak loop (hd0, 1)/home/pepe/Downloads/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso`

Comment: You mean `loopback` (missing c)?